# graph-easy: how to make flowchart?

Tags: linux, graphics, command-line-interface

I am very happy to meet the great software, graph-easy. But I can not much more docs about it. So please someone help me out.
here is my code:

```
[Client] { size: 5,10;}
[Msg Server] { size: 5,10;}
[Server] 

[Server] -- put msg\n
            via http  -->  [Msg Server]


[Msg Server] -- 1. Number X of unread --> [Client]
[Msg Server] -- 3. X Msg --> [Client]

[Client] -- 2. read X --> [Msg Server]
```

And after the command: 

`graph-easy --input flowchart.txt --ascii`

The Result is:
[image]

Here is the problem:

1. how to make the order right? From top to low: 1 2 3
2. the { size:5,10} is not work very well. { size: 5,100} get the same result. why?

Comment: meybe using tikz pgf  http://www.texample.net/  ? or notmal dot http://graphviz.org/

Comment: I want to generate the ascii flowchart. So the latex is not my case.

Answer (score 0):

for problem one.  you can do this:

```
[Msg Server] -- 1. Number X of unread --> {start: front,0}[Client]
[Msg Server] -- 3. X Msg --> {start: front,3} [Client]
[Client] -- 2. read X --> {end: front,2}[Msg Server]
```

for problem two.  google led me to this question as I am also confused about it.

a workaround is to create a hidden edge pointing to some large `port` of the node.  I am sure the node will grow in size automatically, but that's just hacky.